# Constant functions are measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $f = C$ a constant, and I want to show $f$ is measurable.

In other words, if we take $(a, \infty)$, we show $f^{-1} (( a, \infty) )$ is measurable.

But $ f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ is just the real line $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore measurable? Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one of the two parts.

But bear in mind, if $a \ge c$, then $f^{-1}[(a,\infty)] = \varnothing$. Of course, this doesn't alter the conclusion, since $\varnothing$ is also measurable.

Comment: I think if $a > c$ when we have empty set. If $a = c$, then we still have that $f^{-1}((a, \infty)) = \mathbb{R}$. Right?

Comment: No, for $(a,\infty) = \{x \in \Bbb R\mid a < x\}$ and it is not true that $c < c$.

Comment: Got it. thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!